# Determine total turns $N_g$ before the coin slips from the rotating horisontal disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Question: A coin with mass m is placed on a horisontal disk with distance $R$ from the centre of the disk. The disk is rotating at a constant acceleration $  \ddot \theta = a > 0$ and $a(t=0) = 0$ and velocity $v(t=0) = 0$ where $t \geq 0$. The disk is starting at rest. The static friction constant is $u_s$.
Determine the total amount of turns/laps $N_g$ before the coin starts slipping (A lap/turn is $2 \pi$ radians).

Attempt: The magnitude of the frictional force which keeps the coin from slipping outwards from the center is $F(t) \leq u_s \cdot mg$. Let $t=t_s$ be the time when the coin starts slipping. At the time of slipping we have maximum frictional force (1):

$Max[F(t)] = F(t_s) = u_s \cdot mg$.

For circular motion we have the acceleration $v^2/R = R \cdot \dot \theta^2$ towards the center of the disk.

Newtons second law then gives us (2):

$F(t_s) = m \cdot R \cdot \dot \theta^2$.

Solving equation (1) = (2) with respect to $\dot \theta^2$ gives us, at time $t=t_s$ (3):

$\dot \theta^2 = \frac{u_s \cdot g}{R}$.

Since $\ddot \theta = a$ and $\dot \theta (t=0) = 0$ we have $\dot \theta (t) + \dot \theta (t=0) = a \cdot t + 0 = a \cdot t = \dot \theta (t) $.

Now, with $a \cdot t = \dot \theta (t) $ we let $t=t_s$ and solve the following equation with respect to $t_s$:

$ (3) = \dot \theta^2 (t_s) = a^2 \cdot t_s^2 \leftrightarrow \frac{u_s \cdot g}{R} =  a^2 \cdot t_s^2 \leftrightarrow t_s = \sqrt{\frac{u_s \cdot g}{R \cdot a^2}} = (4)$.

We now have the time (4) when the coin starts slipping. Let total number of laps $N_g$ be a function of time $t: N_g (t)$ and can obviously be expressed as $\frac{\theta (t)}{2\cdot \pi}$. So in order to determine $N_g (t_s)$ we are looking for $\theta (t_s)$:

$\ddot \theta (t) = a$

$\dot \theta (t) = a \cdot t$

$ \theta (t) = \frac{a \cdot t^2}{2}$

$ \theta (t_s) = \frac{u_s \cdot g}{2 \cdot R \cdot a} = (5)$

With (5) we finally have the expression for $N_g (t_s)$ :

$N_g (t_s) = \frac{ \theta (t_s) }{2\cdot \pi} = \frac{u_s \cdot g}{4 \cdot \pi \cdot R \cdot a}$

Sadly, this is the wrong answer. Any help appreciated, especially if you can tell me where in my solution I do wrong. I think my error is that I did not include both frictional composants.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's right - you have not included both frictional components, ie tangential as well as radial.

In the rotating frame of reference there are 2 fictitious forces acting on the stationary coin. One is the radial centrifugal force, which you have identified. This corresponds to radial acceleration $r\omega^2$ in the inertial frame of reference. The 2nd fictitious force is tangential, due to the angular acceleration $\alpha$ of the disk. This acts opposite to the direction of tangential acceleration in the inertial frame and causes tangential acceleration $r\alpha$ in the inertial frame of reference.

The real static friction force opposes the **vector resultant** of these two fictitious forces. You must take both into account in deciding when the static limit of friction has been reached.